# Dynamic SQL with parameters is faster than stored procedure?

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I have found that if I have the same query created in code with a parameterized command, then its faster than if I run the same query in a stored procedure with parameters.

Why is this happening?

For example, when I run a query without stored proc , it takes 2 seconds, while if I run it in a stored procedure with parameters then it takes 4 to 5 seconds.

Comment: Don't assume. It is very possible that the query plan is identical and the second call (with dynamic SQL) used a cached plan. It is also possible that you are running these with different parameters and are seeing the results of parameter sniffing. Recommended reading: http://www.sommarskog.se/query-plan-mysteries.html

Comment: My query is same, since I am passing the same set of values to stored procedure and to the parameterized SQL statement in ADO.Net. But still parameterized ADO.Net command query is faster. Actually the stored proc for same parameter values runs forever literally.

Comment: That's not what parameter sniffing is about. Read that article - really.

Comment: Thanks. I just read it. So all parameters must be converted to local variables in the stored proc for parameter sniffing to be removed?

Comment: That was quick. A bit too quick for such a long article. And no, that's not what it is about.

Comment: You are right. There are many aspects highlighted in that useful article, and I will give it a detailed look. Thanks. Please post so I can give you points or mark answer.